# Novel about a magician and his helper, who must maintain the shop after the magician's apprentice is killed

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to find the title of a book I once read - possibly a young adult or children's book. It's about a secluded magical village that is separated from the rest of civilization by a vast expanse. People from the city come to the village for potions and medicines. The story centers around the village magician and his helper (not an apprentice). The magician's apprentice is mean to the helper, who lives in the basement with the cats. He keeps the pantry of herbs stocked and he sneaks books from the magician's library to read at night.

One day the magician's apprentice is found in the woods killed by some unknown creature. The magician has to go away to the city and the helper is left in charge of the shop. He must go to the greenhouse out in the wilderness to resupply the herbs and he finds the greenhouse shattered.

He is befriended by the apprentice to the village healer and they become the main characters trying to determine what's happening in the village. The healer has also disappeared to the city, along with the magician.

The only other thing I remember is it's got something to do with the ancient magicians who have gone on. The magicians become trees and the trees are getting damaged and revolting or fighting back, maybe?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read this?  Do you recall what the cover looked like?

Comment: Hi @DavidW - It's been within the last few years, but I couldn't tell you the date it was published. I would guess it's been published in the last 20 years. I don't remember the cover or any of the characters' names.